# Finalization queue in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalize

Is it the case that only if a class has a `finalize()` method, only then that object, when unreachable, is added to the finalization queue? Reason being I was going through this [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/finalization/)
and in the category *Avoid Memory-Retention Problems When Subclassing* it says that a large array is not available for garbage collection till `finalize()` is called.
But my point is that even if I don't write a `finalize()` method, still it had to wait for the object to be deque'd in the finalization queue.

Comment: classes w/o declared `finalize` method (in any subclass), hence empty `finalize` in `java.lang.Object` are not subject of the finalization queue in all the implementations i know of.

Comment: It does **not** say that a large array is not available until finalized. What it does say is that that the *example* RGBImage class, which contains an array, inherits a finalizer from the Image1 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the case that only if a class has a finalize() method, only then that object, when unreachable, is added to the finalization queue?

Almost. It says that objects whose superclasses have implemented "finalize" are added to the finalization queue when the garbage collector finds them unreachable.